# My .Net code gets a 40 error in named pipes, but Excel connects fine

Tags: .net, sql-server, database-connection

After no luck fixing a problem in my SQL Server Express install, I finally tore down the server, reinstalled SQL Server Express from a fresh installer, and built my data from backups. Now SQL Server Mgmt Studio can connect and query the new database fine, queries through it are OK.

However, my previously working .Net code cannot connect, giving the dreaded 40 error on named pipes. I have run through [this entire list](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2340/resolving-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-errors/) without any problems. Yes, NP is enabled, server is up, browser sees the server, the name is correct, firewall is off, etc etc.

So on a lark I tried Excel using the connection gizmo under "Data". Worked perfectly! So I took the connection string from the properties on the Connection, pasted that into my app, and get a 40 error again.

Here is the original connection string I was using:

```
PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;INITIAL CATALOG=DATA_TEST;Data Source=MAURY-THINK\SQLEXPRESS;
```

Here is the one from Excel,with non-usable tags removed:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=DATA_TEST;Data Source=MAURY-THINK\SQLEXPRESS;Packet Size=4096;
```

So how is it that this works in Excel but not my app? Does anyone have any suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: Are you using a OleDbConnection in .NET or SqlConnection?  Can you enable IP, restart SQL, find the port number in the SQL Log and trcy connecting with IP instead of NP.

Comment: SqlConnection. IP is enabled. 1344. How do I force it to IP instead of NP?

Comment: Assuming your port is actually 1433 (not 1344), then `Server=MAURY-THING;Database=DATA_TEST;Integrated Security=true` should work.

Comment: And it did, yesterday.

Comment: To explicitly set a port use `tcp:MAURY-THING,12323`. 
 for the Server/Data Source.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8  And check the SQL Log to verify the port, and for details about the login failure (if it's not a network issue).

Comment: I used the string you posted in the 3rd line verbatim, and get a 25 error. I added \SQLEXPRESS (which i assume you meant to include) and get the 40. I do not understand the syntax of your last post, where do I put that "tcp" text?

Comment: Sorry,I figured out the syntax. provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The remote computer refused the network connection

Comment: Good.  So check the SQL Log to verify the port.  Looks like it's not listening on the port you think it is.  And if this is a remote computer, check the Windows Firewall too.